# Arearange highchart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to make an arearange series like the following? :
 [image]

I saw the option to set oppacity, but that will give the series like the following:
 [image]

Is there a way to hide the top line or to set the opacity of top line only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set only `lineWidth` for whole area-range series. Instead you can disable that line, and use separate series: http://jsfiddle.net/9agdf5ar/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Range',
        data: ranges,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true  
        },
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0
    }]
```